# why condition is always true in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Could you please tell me why **my condition is always true**? I am trying to validate my value using regex.i have few conditions

1. Name should not contain test "text"
2. Name should not contain three consecutive characters example "abc" , "pqr" ,"xyz"
3. Name should not contain the same character three times example "aaa", "ccc" ,"zzz"

I do like this

https://jsfiddle.net/aoerLqkz/2/

```
var val = 'ab dd'

if (/test|[^a-z]|(.)\1\1|abc|bcd|cde|def|efg|fgh|ghi|hij|ijk|jkl|klm|lmn|mno|nop|opq|pqr|qrs|rst|stu|tuv|uvw|vwx|wxy|xyz/i.test(val)) {
                       alert( 'match')
                    } else {
   alert( 'false')
   }
```

I tested my code with the following string and getting an unexpected result

1. **input string** "abc" : **output fine** :: "match"
2. **input string** "aaa" : **output fine** :: "match"
3. **input string** "aa a" : **output ** :: "match" why it is match ?? there is space between them why it matched ????

   **input string** "sa c" : **output ** :: "match" why it is match ?? there is different string and space between them  ????

Comment: @Martijn — That's **not** a-z

Comment: "test text" or "text test"?

Comment: Why *wouldn't* `"aa a"` be matched? Your pattern (second branch) says "any non-letter" and a space is not a letter. It's the same if you enter `"aa1a"` - the number one is not a letter, hence it's matched.

Comment: There's no law that says you have to write one giant regex. This is a lot easier to write and to understand if you use three smaller regexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the `[^a-z]`. This means that any string that has a non-letter character anywhere in it will be a match. In your example, it is matching the space character.

The solution? Simply remove `|[^a-z]`. Without it, your regex meets all three criteria.

1. `test` checks if the value contains the word 'test'.
2. `abc|bcd|cde|def|efg|fgh|ghi|hij|ijk|jkl|klm|lmn|mno|nop|opq|pqr|qrs|rst|stu|tuv|uvw|vwx|wxy|xyz` checks if the value contains three sequential letters.
3. `(.)\1\1` checks if any character is repeated three times.

Complete regex:

```
/test|(.)\1\1|abc|bcd|cde|def|efg|fgh|ghi|hij|ijk|jkl|klm|lmn|mno|nop|opq|pqr|qrs|rst|stu|tuv|uvw|vwx|wxy|xyz/i`
```

I find it helpful to use a regex tester, like https://www.regexpal.com/, when writing regular expressions.

NOTE: I am assuming that the second criteria actually means "three consecutive letters", not "three consecutive characters" as it is written. If that is not true, then your regex doesn't meet the second criteria, since it only checks for three consecutive letters.

Answer (score 9):

The string `sa c` includes a space, the pattern `[^a-z]` (not a to z) matches the space.

Possibly you want to use `^` and `$` so your pattern also matches the start and end of the string instead of looking for a match anywhere inside it.

Comment: what is the correct regex ..!! please change my fiddle to get expected result

Comment: @joy it's probably more useful for you to modify the regex yourself... to reinforce your understanding of this answer.

Comment: @Joy For the question as written, just remove the `[^a-z]` branch of the regex; however, presumably you had some reason to add this, so we can only guess what you wanted it to do.

Comment: I have only three condition .pls see above three conditions

Answer (score 5):

> there is space between them why it matched ????

Because of the `[^a-z]` part of your regular expression, which matches the space:

```
> /[^a-z]/i.test('aa a');
true
```

Comment: what is the correct regex ..!! please change my fiddle to get expected result

Comment: @Joy It's impossible to tell, because this part of the regex is a fourth condition not listed in your question. For the conditions as written, you don't need the `[^a-z]` part at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would not do this with regular expresions, this expresion will always get more complicated and you have not the possibilities you had if you programmed this.

The rules you said suggest the concept of string derivative. The derivative of a string is the distance between each succesive character. It is specially useful dealing with password security checking and string variation in general.

```js
const derivative = (str) => {
  const result = [];
  for(let i=1; i<str.length; i++){
    result.push(str.charCodeAt(i) - str.charCodeAt(i-1));
  }
  return result;
  };

//these strings have the same derivative: [0,0,0,0]
console.log(derivative('aaaaa'));
console.log(derivative('bbbbb'));

//these strings also have the same derivative: [1,1,1,1]
console.log(derivative('abcde'));
console.log(derivative('mnopq'));

//up and down: [1,-1, 1,-1, 1]
console.log(derivative('ababa'));
```

With this in mind you can apply your each of your rules to each string.

```js
//    Rules:
// 1.   Name should not contain test "text"
// 2.   Name should not contain three consecutive characters example "abc" , "pqr" ,"xyz"
// 3.   Name should not contain the same character three times example "aaa", "ccc" ,"zzz"

const derivative = (str) => {
  const result = [];
  for(let i=1; i<str.length; i++){
    result.push(str.charCodeAt(i) - str.charCodeAt(i-1));
  }
  return result;
  };
  
const arrayContains = (master, sub) => 
    master.join(",").indexOf( sub.join( "," ) ) == -1;


const rule1 = (text) => !text.includes('text');

const rule2 = (text) => !arrayContains(derivative(text),[1,1]);

const rule3 = (text) => !arrayContains(derivative(text),[0,0]);

const testing = [
  "smthing textual",'abc','aaa','xyz','12345',
  '1111','12abb', 'goodbcd', 'weeell'
];

const results = testing.map((input)=>
  [input, rule1(input), rule2(input), rule3(input)]);

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the 3 conditions in the post, the following regex should work.

Regex: `^(?:(?!test|([a-z])\1\1|abc|bcd|cde|def|efg|fgh|ghi|hij|ijk|jkl|klm|lmn|mno|nop|opq|pqr|qrs|rst|stu|tuv|uvw|vwx|wxy|xyz).)*$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9klNmk/1)

Comment: This doesn't make any attempt to answer the question, _"why is my condition always true?"_

Comment: @canon, I agree. There is more than 1 answer to this post that addresses that specific question correctly. However, I felt the OP's regex was not matching the listed conditions.